# C# Masterpage picture being stretched when opening other webpages

Tags: c#, master-pages

I have a picture of our logo on my master page and previously when I opened other pages on the website the picture was the same size.  When I updated the picture to a new one the master page looks find but when I open other pages the picture is stretched (see links).
[Master Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2O5d8.png)        [Sub Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOMer.png)

This is my code for the masterpage upto the point where the picture comes into play:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="OnCallWeb.MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Union County Dispatch Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MenuStyle.css" />
    <style>
        body {
            background-color:gainsboro;
            background-size:cover;
            background-attachment:fixed;
        }

        .auto-style1 {
            width: 783px;
            height: 137px;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            left: 0;
            top: -1px;
            width: 100%;
        }

    </style>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <nav class="auto-style2">
               <div><img src="~/img/OnCallWebLogo2022.png" runat="server" class="auto-style1" /></div>
                <label class="toggle" for="drop">Menu</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
```

Comment: Maybe you should re-ask your question tagging it under css help.  If your old picture size is different from new picture - I would start there - maybe re-size the photo compared to old one = keeping aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by altering the size of the orginal png file.